# Is there a way to set up Oracle on Mac Lion without VM?

Tags: mac-osx, oracle-11g

I really would like to avoid having to install virtual box just to use Oracle 11g. Is there a way to install it into Mac OSX?

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Database 11g runs only on](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) Windows, Linux, Solaris, HP-UX or AIX.

If you want to run it on a Macintosh, it must be running one of the supported operating systems.

So you either must reboot to a supported OS with BootCamp or install a virtualized OS with VirtualBox, VMware Fusion or something else.

Comment: I was hoping you didn't say that. I have Windows on BootCamp, but it's so inconvenient.

Comment: You might like @ewwhite's solution. It looks painful though, and you can be sure Oracle won't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the detailed instructions for accomplishing this on Stack Overflow:

[Installing Oracle 11g on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992735/560492)

You won't need a permanent virtualized installation, but it is necessary for the initial install.

Comment: Are you talking about Oracle Database 11g ?